# How to upload an update of an app in play store?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an app in play store versioned 2.0. Now I want to release an update 2.1 but I get this error

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2.
```

How to upload my new release as 2.1 instead of 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version code is always upgrade...its not decresed...but you can set version name manually..

please  change versionCode 3.0 instead of 2.0,but you have to set   **android:versionName="2.1"**  and  **android:versionCode="3"**

I hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the version code in AndroidManifest file. 2.1 or 3.0 is usually the version name, which are displayed to users. Version code is the one you maintained to mark your code version.

I prefer to just use 1, 2, 3, ... for version code
and use others like 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, ... for version name.

So you just need to set android:versionCode="3" and android:versionName="2.1".